# vscode: is there an api for accessing config values from a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for vscode 1.12.2 and I am trying to determine the default theme.  Atom Editor has a nice [API for accessing config values](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.17.0/Config), e.g.:

```
atom.config.defaultSettings.core.themes[0]
"one-dark-ui"
atom.config.defaultSettings.core.themes[1]
"one-dark-syntax"
```

Is there something similar to this in vscode?

I can see the value 'workbench.colorTheme' in `~/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json`:

```
   // "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe"
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/k",
        "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
    ],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+" <-- here
```

However, I'd rather not resort to a custom solution whereby I directly read the config file as JSON, especially since it allows non-default JSON values such as comments, which I would presumably have to pre-parse-out.

While this question is narrowly directed at determining the theme, it really applies to any config parm.  I didn't see anything in the [vscode html api](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_env) or in browsing the typings file `/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/vscode.d.ts`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you try:

```
const workbenchConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workbench')
const theme = workbenchConfig.get('colorTheme')
```

Here's the documentation on the configuration object: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Comment: Worked for me, as have most all your answers.